# ui-router with ngAA angular js1

Tags: angularjs

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("ng-app",[
   'ui.router',
   'oc.lazyLoad',
   'ngMaterial',
   'ngAnimate',
   'ngMessages',
   'ngAria',
   'ngAA',
   'ngRoute',
   'ngCookies',
   'thatisuday.dropzone'
]);
```

**config.route.js**

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, dropzoneOpsProvider, $authProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider, $mdThemingProvider, $mdIconProvider, $locationProvider, site_settings) {

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector) {

    var $state = $injector.get("$state");
    $state.go('login');
});
$mdIconProvider.defaultIconSet('assets/angular-material-assets/img/icons/core-icons.svg', 24);


$authProvider.signinUrl = site_settings.api_url + 'authenticate';
$authProvider.signinState = 'login';
$authProvider.signinRoute = '/login';
$authProvider.signinTemplateUrl = 'module/auth/views/login.html';
$authProvider.afterSigninRedirectTo = 'timeline';
$authProvider.afterSignoutRedirectTo = 'login';

$stateProvider
        .state('index', {
            abstract: true,
            views: {
                '@': {
                    templateUrl: 'module/general/views/main.html',
                    controller: 'mainController'
                },
                'navbar@index': {
                    templateUrl: 'module/general/views/navbar.html'
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                dep: ['$ocLazyLoad',
                    function ($ocLazyLoad) {

                        return $ocLazyLoad.load(['module/general/mainController.js']).then(function (response) {

                        });
                    }]
            }
        })
        .state('signup', {
            //parent: 'index',
            url: '/register',
            views: {
                'content': {
                    templateUrl: 'module/auth/views/signup.html',
                    controller: 'authController'
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                dep: ['$ocLazyLoad',
                    function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                        return $ocLazyLoad.load(['module/auth/authController.js']);
                    }]
            }
        })
        .state('timeline', {
            parent: 'index',
            url: '/timeline',
            views: {
                'content': {
                    templateUrl: 'module/timeline/views/timeline.html',
                    controller: 'timelineController'
                }
            },
            data: {
                authenticated: true
            },
            resolve: {
                dep: ['$ocLazyLoad',
                    function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                        return $ocLazyLoad.load(['module/timeline/TimelineController.js']);
                    }]
            }
        })
        .state('profile', {
            parent: 'index',
            url: '/profile/:id',
            views: {
                'content': {
                    templateUrl: 'module/profile/views/profile.html',
                    controller: 'ProfileController'
                }
            },
            data: {
                authenticated: true
            },
            resolve: {
                dep: ['$ocLazyLoad',
                    function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                        return $ocLazyLoad.load(['module/profile/ProfileController.js']);
                    }],
            }
        });
});
```

In this code when I move to state timeline/profile without authentication, they allow me to go to a state where I already use

```
data:{
    authentication:true
 }
```

But this is not working for me.There is no error. I also tried "requiresLogin:true" but it is also not working. Sign in/Signup working properly.
In given below image timeline.html and other html are already loaded and they get response from backend,it redirects back to login.This should happen at fronted instead of backend.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWONz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code has no error,just there is two packages named ui-router in npm.So I installed ui-router using (UI-Router version 1.0 alpha)

```
npm install ui-router
```

instead of

```
npm install angular-ui-router
```

and deleted old node package.